# Magento 2.1.3 to 2.2.5 Upgrade Error

Tags: magento-2.1.3, magento-upgrade

I tried upgrading Magento 2.1.3 to Magento 2.2.5, But I faced some errors after running composer update. Any Ideas?

Here's the error codes:

```
 Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install magento/product-community-edition 2.2.5
- magento/framework 100.1.3 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.11, 2.4.10, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].
- magento/framework 100.1.3 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.11, 2.4.10, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].
- magento/framework 100.1.4 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.11, 2.4.10, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].
- magento/framework 100.1.5 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.11, 2.4.10, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].
- magento/framework 100.1.6 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.11, 2.4.10, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].
- magento/framework 100.1.7 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.11, 2.4.10, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].
- magento/framework 100.1.8 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.11, 2.4.10, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].
- magento/framework 100.1.9 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.11, 2.4.10, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].
- magento/framework 100.1.10 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.11, 2.4.10, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].
- magento/framework 100.1.11 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.11, 2.4.10, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].
- magento/framework 100.1.12 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.11, 2.4.10, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].
- magento/framework 100.1.13 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.11, 2.4.10, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].
- magento/framework 100.1.14 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.11, 2.4.10, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].
- magento/framework 100.1.3 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.11, 2.4.10, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].
- magento/framework 100.1.4 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.11, 2.4.10, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].
- magento/framework 100.1.5 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.11, 2.4.10, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].
- magento/framework 100.1.6 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.11, 2.4.10, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].
- magento/framework 100.1.7 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.11, 2.4.10, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].
- magento/framework 100.1.8 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.11, 2.4.10, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].
- magento/framework 100.1.9 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.11, 2.4.10, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].
- magento/framework 100.1.10 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.11, 2.4.10, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].
- magento/framework 100.1.11 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.11, 2.4.10, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].
- magento/framework 100.1.12 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.11, 2.4.10, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].
- magento/framework 100.1.13 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.11, 2.4.10, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].
- magento/framework 100.1.14 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.11, 2.4.10, 2.4.12, 2.4.13, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].
- magento/framework 100.2.0-rc20 requires tedivm/jshrink ~1.1.0 -> satisfiable by tedivm/jshrink[v1.1.0].
- magento/framework 100.2.0-rc20 requires tedivm/jshrink ~1.1.0 -> satisfiable by tedivm/jshrink[v1.1.0].
- Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7, 2.4.10].
- Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7, 2.4.11].
- Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7, 2.4.12].
- Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7, 2.4.13].
- Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7, 2.4.6].
- Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7, 2.4.7].
- Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7, 2.4.8].
- Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7, 2.4.9].
- Can only install one of: zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7, 2.4.11].
- Can only install one of: tedivm/jshrink[v1.3.0, v1.1.0].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.2.5 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ^2.7.7 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.7.7].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.2.5 requires tedivm/jshrink ~1.3.0 -> satisfiable by tedivm/jshrink[v1.3.0].
- Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.2.5 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.5].
- magento/data-migration-tool 2.1.3 requires magento/framework ~100.1 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.3, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 100.2.0-rc20, 100.1.9, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 100.1.12, 100.1.13, 100.1.14].
- magento/data-migration-tool 2.1.3 requires magento/framework ~100.1 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.3, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 100.2.0-rc20, 100.1.9, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 100.1.12, 100.1.13, 100.1.14].
- magento/data-migration-tool 2.1.3 requires magento/framework ~100.1 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.3, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 100.2.0-rc20, 100.1.9, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 100.1.12, 100.1.13, 100.1.14].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.5, 100.1.0-rc1].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.5, 100.1.0-rc2].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.5, 100.1.0-rc3].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.5, 100.1.0].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.5, 100.1.1].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.5, 100.1.2].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.5, 100.1.0-rc1].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.5, 100.1.0-rc2].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.5, 100.1.0-rc3].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.5, 100.1.0].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.5, 100.1.1].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.5, 100.1.2].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.2.5 requires magento/framework 101.0.5 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[101.0.5].
- Conclusion: don't install magento/framework 101.0.5
- Installation request for magento/data-migration-tool 2.1.3 -> satisfiable by magento/data-migration-tool[2.1.3].
```

Here's my composer.json file

```
{
"name": "magento/project-community-edition",
"description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
"type": "project",
"version": "2.1.3",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.2.5",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",
    "magento/data-migration-tool": "2.1.3",
    "mirasvit/module-search-ultimate": "^1.0",
    "kodbruket/magento2-gtm": "^1.0",
    "magewonder/magento2-smtp": "^1.2"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.2.2",
    "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
},
"config": {
    "use-include-path": true
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": "app/code/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "alpha",
"prefer-stable": true,
"repositories": {
    "0": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    },
    "magento": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com"
    },
    "mirasvit-ssu2": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://16715:L9IJ8A7G04@packages.mirasvit.com/"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override"
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a version of each data-migration-tool for each version of Magento.
You have to update your data-migration-tool to 2.2.5 as well.